# How do I interpret K-means model output from Pyspark ml. clustering library?

Tags: clustering, interpretation, model, k-means, spark-mllib

I am new to PySpark and learning how to build models using PySpark's machine learning libraries. I build a k-means clustering algorithm based on the code of this [website](https://runawayhorse001.github.io/LearningApacheSpark/clustering.html). Now, I fed my data into the algorithm and get the output depicted in the following image: [image]. I used 60 centroids have 142 features. How do I interpret this graph ?

Comment: How many data points were in your original dataset?  Looking at the first 9 features there does not seem to be a significant different between the 60 Centroids, maybe other features have a greater differentiation.  Why so many centroids?

Comment: There were 1,000 data-points. I chose 60 Centroids using the Elbow-Method. I used a one-hot encoding to encode my features as described on the website. Do you think this could have caused that there is no difference between the 60 Centroids?